# How to compile the CPython python interpreter from source and build an installer for it

Tags: python

I don't even know the right way to put my question but i will try my best. 
I downloaded (Python-3.4.2.tar) the source code of a python interpreter from www.python.org
I extracted the files(using 7-zip).
Now lets say i latter want to use the unziped/extracted fies to create an installer i.e put it in a form that i can double click and Python-3.4.2 will be installed in my computer.
i guess it is called creating a build distriution.
I know i can just download Python-3.4.2.exe from the site and install right away but i want to know how it goes from being source code to becoming something one can install.

Comment: You're a bit over the place here.  I *sort of* understand, but want you to clarify.  First, are you talking about creating an easy-to-use form to download and install Python?  Are you trying to figure out how the C code (since Python is written in C) goes from being source to installable?

Comment: You would need to compile it, probably with Microsoft Visual C.  I have no idea how the Python developers have this set up, but I imagine it involves a Makefile.  That would give you the `Python.exe` file that can actually run Python code.  You'd then need to wrap it in an MSI installer, to put the `Python.exe` file somewhere useful and tell the operating system to use it when you double click on Python files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starting point for compiling:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/PCbuild/readme.txt

I was able to compile 2.7.13 with:

```
cd PCBuild
cmd /c get_externals.bat
cmd /c build.bat -e  --no-tkinter "/p:PlatformToolset=v100"
```

3.4 may require a later compiler.

Here's how to build an installer:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Tools/msi/README.txt

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I think what you are asking is how you can distribute the Python runtime along with your program. The process is pretty simple. First, you may want to take a look at Python's [distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/). Secondly, you will need to distribute the Python runtime. Python is currently released within installation binaries for pretty much every major operating system. You have the option of compiling target system(s) yourself in order to make Python silently install.

You will then need to decide where you want the files to go. Most people don't like this sort of behavior, so I recommend putting the files in *your* programs directory. Shortcuts, system variables, et cetera will need to be looked into.

As another option you can consider porting your script(s) to Jython, as most people tend to have at least the Java runtime. In the process of porting your code there is a way of constructing Java `.class` files with Jython when coded a certain way. They can then be placed into an executable `Jar` file. Easy peasy, but I haven't tried this myself, to be honest.

If you want to stick with pure Python, the last hurtle is putting everything in one file. There are plenty of tools for that. I would try Github for starters. For bonus points you can always code your own self-extracting binary.

Post Script: With the title changed, I think you are looking for [Creating Build Distributions](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html). It is the second link within the Google results for the query "how to compile python installer". Further down the same page I found [this gem](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

For building the CPython python interpreter from source, you'll want to have a look at the instructions at https://docs.python.org/devguide/

These instructions probably also (somewhere) contain the steps to produce a Windows installer, which [seems to be done with some tool called `PCbuild`](https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows-compiling).