# CPython installer

Tags: windows-installer, cpython

### Background

I am successfully building CPython on [windows](https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows-compiling) using the `PYTHONSOURCE\PCBuild\build.bat` script.

```
PCBuild\build.bat -e
```

All of the compiled/built files are placed into a folder under `PYTHONSOURCE\PCBuild\amd64`, so far so good.

### Problem

According to the docs specifying `/p:OutputDir=A:\PATH\FOR\PYTHON` should allow me to specify the build location but this does not do the right thing. Specifically this only applies to the Visual C Projects being built and any supporting libraries e.g. TCl/Tk do not install correctly. Furthermore the final folder structure is nothing like my existing python installation structure. Superficially the the differences I can see include :

- TCL/Tk does not copy across to `A:\PATH\FOR\PYTHON`
- The *.h files needed by other programs that link to Python are not copied across (They aren't present in the original location either)
- Comparing `A:\PATH\FOR\PYTHON` to my existing python install I'm missing the following sub-directories

  - DLLs/libs/man/Scripts/share  : How are these folders populated ?
  - Lib/include/Tools            : Are these simply copied from the Python sources ? They do not appear to match up 100% and do not have a 1 to 1 mapping.
  - Docs                         : I found [Building the Documentation](https://docs.python.org/devguide/documenting.html#building-doc)
- Does the Python installer set some windows registry keys ? If so how does it do this.

### Question

How does one go from building the sources to a proper installation. Is there some blog describing how to build the Python Installer/Distribution.

### Research

Googling "CPython", "distribution", "install(er)", "bundle(r)" and variations thereof lead mostly to information about "Packaging Python Modules" and not "Packaging CPython" which is decidedly different. This does not appear to be mentioned in the [developers guide](https://docs.python.org/devguide/) nor the nearest matching [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28652978/958580) question.

### Purpose

I'm probably trying to cut myself on the bleeding edge here but I've started converting from using static installs/releases to nightly builds on all the projects I'm using. I struck upon this problem while trying to build mod_wsgi which requires Apache, Python and mod_wsgi to be built with the same compiler and found the python build to be unsuitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Fudge the folder `PYTHONSOURCE\Tools\msi` contains msi.py which apparently solves this. I'm still confirming this so any input is welcome.